# Quarkus read `ResultSet` and process with multi-threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, quarkus

I'm trying to read a JDBC `ResultSet` in parallel and do some processing on each record in a Quarkus service. There could be lots of records in the `ResultSet` so I don't want to read all the data upfront. I'd rather stream the results to a processor.

I have wrapped the `ResultSet` object so I can read from it in a thread safe manner. However I am struggling to find a way to read the results in multiple threads. I've tried an `ExecutorService` but the DB context gets lost and the `ResultSet` is closed in the thread.

I considered using a SmallRye `Multi` object to do the processing, but I struggled to find a way to add the records to the item list and I'm not sure that will create multiple threads anyway.

Is there a preferred multi-threading library for Quarkus?

Comment: If you're losing the DB context it's probably because the threads that do the concurrent process outlive the one that did the DB query, right? If so, the problem isn't how to spawn the threads, but how to keep the DB context alive until everything is finished. Or, perhaps, to covert the DB result set into some other object with a longer lifetime. Managing the context is going to be a problem, whatever kind of concurrent execution you choose, I think.

Comment: Not much point to this. The connection isn't multi-threaded. Use a single thread. Use the thread that obtained the `ResultSet`. Otherwise you run into connection liveness problems, as you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use producer-consumer pattern: one thread opens database connection, reads data from ResultSet and places it into Blocking Queue with some limited size and several other threads get data from that blocking queue and process it